# Chrome extension keeps getting rejected

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension has been rejected twice and the reason from the email is

> it currently does not work or provide any functionality upon
>   installation.

However, I have tested it on multiple computers with different accounts and it works fine. I sent an email back asking for clarification and they sent me the same email, but with the above quote highlighted in bold.

I emailed them again asking for further clarification but I don't think I'll be receiving it any time soon.

I believe the issue may be that I am **defining the key in the manifest file**, I read that you aren't supposed to do this (from a post from 2014). However, I'm using the key from the developer dashboard after uploading my extension.

Removing the key isn't mentioned in the publishing guide so I want to make sure before resubmitting (repeatedly resubmitted results in an account suspension).

Thank you for your time, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your using relative paths, you shouldn't need the `key` in your manifest at all. In fact - it's bad practice to be using it in a release version, as it implies your relining on hard codded static resources

Comment: Did you try your extensions as unpacked folder or as crx file?

Comment: It works as an unpacked folder, packing the extension and trying it makes my oauth2 fail (it just keeps requesting the user to log in).

Comment: what does your extension do?